# Joining two tables in PHP/MySQL and displaying elements from both when data from one table is null and the other table's data is not

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one contains the articles posted to a blog page, the second table contains the comments to these articles.

I am using the below function to `JOIN` these and display data from both.

```
function list_articles() { 
    include('core/db/db_connection.php');
    $sql = "SELECT blog.title, blog.content, blog.posted_by, blog.date, article_comments.comments, article_comments.comment_by
                FROM blog INNER JOIN article_comments
                ON blog.content_id = article_comments.comment_id
                -- WHERE blog.content != '' AND article_comments.comment_id != ''
                ORDER BY blog.content_id DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo 
            "<h5 class='posted_by'>Posted by " . $posted_by = $row['posted_by'] . " on " . $row['date'] . "</h5>" . 
            "<h1 class='content_headers'>" . $title = $row['title'] . "</h1>" . 
            "<article>" . $content = $row['content'] . "</article>" . 
            "<hr class='artline'>" . 
            "<div class='commented_by'>" . $row['comment_by'] . "</div>" . 
            "<div class='comments'>" . $row['comments'] . "</div>";
    }
```

The problem that I have is that whenever a user is inserting a new blog post, this won't show on the web page. If I insert a comment in the other table (which matches by ID), the article appears just fine. How can I display these articles even if there are no comments associated with them?

I have tried `-- WHERE blog.content != '' AND article_comments.comment_id = '' OR article_comments.comment_ID = ''` but it has no effect

Also, could you please advise if there is a better way to target these rather than by ID?

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Joining them by ID is correct if the related column in each table is `content_id ->  comment_id`.  But a `LEFT JOIN` is needed to allow the row to return when the relationship is not met in the `article_comments` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
FROM blog INNER JOIN article_comments
```

with this:

```
FROM blog LEFT OUTER JOIN article_comments
```

An `INNER JOIN` requires that the table being joined includes matching records, essentially filtering from the results any row which isn't in both tables.  An `OUTER JOIN` will show all records from the first table (which match the `WHERE` clause, of course) and also join records from the second table where applicable.

Comment: David, one more question: Is it possible to link column_id from table A with column_id from table B?

For example: If column_id A has a value of 6, column_id B should not  allow entries if the column_id B is more than the value of column id A.